# How to find the index number of renamed sheets in excel-vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 8 sheets in a workbook with different names. Is there a way using VBA to activate one ore more of these sheets based on their index number? For example I have sheets named, "Month", "Name", "Age" etc... how can I find their index number?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this

`Sheets("<sheet Name>").Index`

If you want to get code name

`Sheets("<sheet Name>").codename`

> It’s possible for the sheet name to be different from the code name. When you create a sheet, the sheet name and code name are the same, but changing the sheet name doesn’t change the code name, and changing the code name (using the Properties window in the Visual Basic Editor) doesn’t change the sheet name.

Answer (score 4):

To get a sheet's index:
`sheets("month").index`

To activate by index:
`sheets(5).activate`